# Add Custom Label to Django Model Instances

Tags: python, django, django-models

For some background, I have two main models that I am focusing on in my Django webapp.

**The first is a model which contains specific stages of testing of a product:**

```
class TestStage(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    order = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']
```

All test stage instances created from this model will have a set name tied to it's primary key.

**The second is a model which defines products. Each product has it's own list of test stages that it performs, but not all test insertions are used for all products:**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    # more fields...

    test_stages = models.TextField()
```

The test stages are stored as a list within the `TextField`, with individual data stored as a dictionary. Currently, this is operating fine but now I need the ability to add a custom product-specific label for each test insertion.

For example:

Product1 and Product2 both have TestStage1 but Product1 calls its version X, and Product2 calls its version Y.

They both have TestStage1 but have their own specific naming convention.

I am not sure how to accomplish this, also not sure whether this would be accomplished with a field label or use of the `Meta` class...

Comment: having used a manytomany with a through model would have simplified the scenario, why the serialized dict?

Comment: I am not 100% sure. This is legacy code that I did not initially write.

Answer (score 2):

Could you use a m2m with a intermediary model?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    # more fields...
    test_stages = models.ManyToManyField(TestStage, through='ProductTestStage')

class ProductTestStage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    test_stage = models.ForeignKey(TestStage)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Comment: Too add to this, don't feel like you need to even use a m2m. A connection model like this is perfectly sufficient (in other words, leave the `test_stages` field out of the `Product` model, opting instead to manage the relationship using `TestInsertion`. Using m2m with `through` defined removes `.add(...)` method from the field, since Django has no way of knowing what fields you have on that `through` model (hence, my recommendation of leaving the m2m out).

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the update. I removed that portion of the previous comment, for posterity.

Comment: You're right. I changed the class name to ProductTestStage.

Comment: Thank you for your timely responses.

I should have mentioned that Product also tracking revisions and stores them as HistoricalProduct data. The app has views that highlight revisions differences.

With each TestStage associated with a product having data tables linked, I need to make sure the primary keys don't change so that comparisons can be made.

orokusaki: referring to Kaken Lid's post initial post, are you saying that test_stages should not be a part of the Product model definition?

Comment: Are you saying that I should include all the following models into my models.py?

class Product
class TestStage
class ProductTestStage

What is through='TestInsertion' doing?

Comment: `TestInsertion` was a typo. I changed the name of the class to `ProductTestStage`, but forgot to change it both places.

In my code snippet, `test_stages` is not a TextField but a many to many relation. Read the documentation that I linked to for an explanation of how 'through' works.

The revision history sounds like a seperate question, and it's hard to suggest anything without seeing all your models.